# php - One domain to each user account url in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I'm developing a wedding site to my own wedding, and I have some friends who want to use it.

I just the pattern to match username after domain like this:

`http://example.com/username => route to controler/index/username`

`http://example.com/username2 => route to controler/index/username2`

And etc...

Now I want to do this:

`www.username.com => route to controler/index/username`

`www.username2.com => route to controler/index/username2`

But I want to hold both methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve this problem in CI. It would need to be with apaches domain rewrite as that would format the proper redirect

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName www.example.com
  Redirect 301 / http://example.com/username
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use

```
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=<?php echo $adr; ?>">
```

and use [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to get the current adress. (F.ex. "username" and redirect to http://www.username.com.)